# Why my code doesn't work?

Tags: php, mysql

I am using the following code:

```
$db = JFactory::getDBO();
$query = $db->getQuery(true);
$query->select('name')
    ->from ('#__gruposlocales');
$query-> where('latitudX = ' . (int) $lat);
$resu = $db->loadObject();
$gro=$resu->name;
echo "<p>Gruposs: $gro</p>";
```

where `$lat` is a variable from a previous code and its value is `-0.180653`. The code doesn't work; it shows nothing after "Gruposs".

If I use `$query-> where('latitudX = -0.180653');` instead, the code works perfectly, showing a name. If in the upper code, I use `echo "<p>Gruposs: $lat</p>";` it shows `-0.180653`, telling me that the `$lat` variable is being passed correctly.

I am using the same code syntax in a previous part of my code with a different table and a variable in the "where" statement and it works perfectly. Why doesn't my code work with the `$lat` variable in the "where" statement?

Comment: Please state, in your question, the Data Type of the `latitudX` column.  Is it `FLOAT`, `DOUBLE`, `DECIMAL`, `VARCHAR`?  This will perhaps lead to an acceptable answer and/or help a future researcher with their issue.

Comment: I am quite surprised that Richard's solution didn't fix the issue -- this is what I would recommend as well.  Perhaps the implementation of his advice is incorrect.  Can you show how you implemented float casting (show us your updated snippet)?  Also, can you call `var_dump($lat);` and tell us what that prints to screen? This will help us to isolate if you have any invisible characters or something wonky.  Please continue to improve and clarify your question so that this page can be officially resolved.

Answer (score 2):

(int) creates an integer, so `(int) $lat` will remove the bit after the decimal point, ie it will equal 0.

Use `(float) $lat` instead if you want to convert a string to a floating point number.

Comment: Thank you Richard. Your suggestion did not work either but I found that this works:  $query-> where('latitudX ='. $lat);

Comment: @PabloCastelo - just make sure that you have validated and sanitized the $lat variable that you pass into your database, if it comes from user input.